# How to download data from web? Need to skip and move to next item if data doesn't exist

Tags: r, csv

I’m trying to modify a script that I found online.  I want to get the script to skip a ticker if no results are found, kind of like Try…Catch.  Now, the code just falls down if a ticker isn’t found.  How can I get this to skip any/all missing tickers and finish without crashing?

```
require(XML)
require(plyr)

getKeyStats_xpath <- function(symbol) {
  yahoo.URL <- "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s="
  html_text <- htmlParse(paste(yahoo.URL, symbol, sep = ""), encoding="UTF-8")

  #search for <td> nodes anywhere that have class 'yfnc_tablehead1'
  nodes <- getNodeSet(html_text, "/*//td[@class='yfnc_tablehead1']")

  if(length(nodes) > 0 ) {
    measures <- sapply(nodes, xmlValue)

    #Clean up the column name
    measures <- gsub(" *[0-9]*:", "", gsub(" \\(.*?\\)[0-9]*:","", measures))   

    #Remove dups
    dups <- which(duplicated(measures))
    #print(dups) 
    for(i in 1:length(dups)) 
      measures[dups[i]] = paste(measures[dups[i]], i, sep=" ")

    #use siblings function to get value
    values <- sapply(nodes, function(x)  xmlValue(getSibling(x)))

    df <- data.frame(t(values))
    colnames(df) <- measures
    return(df)
  } else {
    break
  }
}

setwd("C:/Users/rshuell001/Desktop/downloads/")

tickers <- c("OREX",
"OSIR",
"PACB",
"PCRX",
"PCYC",
"PDLI",
"PETX",
"PGNX",
"POZN",
"PRTA",
"PTCT",
"PTLA",
"PTX",
"QGEN",
"QLTI",
"RARE",
"RCPT",
"RDUS",
"REGN",
"RGEN",
"RGLS",
"RLYP",
"RPTP",
"RTRX",
"RVNC",
"SAGE")

stats <- ldply(tickers, getKeyStats_xpath)
rownames(stats) <- tickers
write.csv(t(stats), "FinancialStats_updated.csv",row.names=TRUE)
```

I posted here about a week ago and a couple people suggested I try this.

```
stats <- llply(tickers, function(t) tryCatch(getKeyStats_xpath(t), error=function(x) {cat("error occurred, skipping this ticker\n")}))
rownames(stats) <- tickers
write.csv(t(stats), "FinancialStats_updated.csv",row.names=TRUE)
```

That never worked.  I messed around with it for a while, but couldn’t get it to write the data to a CSV file.  Although, the code looks like it’s pretty close to what I want.

Can someone help me get this straightened out?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the error your code produces:

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
>
> no loop for break/next, jumping to top level

Let's look at `help(break)`:

> break breaks out of a for, while or repeat loop; control is transferred to the first statement outside the inner-most loop

So, `break()` may only be used in a for, while or repeat loop, and you are using it in an if else statement... We could just replace that break in `getKeyStats_xpath` by something else. Plus return something to mark that there was a symbol not found.

```
...
  } else {
    cat("Could not find",symbol,"\n")
    return(data.frame(NA))
  }
...
```

It now works fine. You can remove the rows that are all NAs, after you have assigned names to stats, with:

```
stats <- stats[!rowSums(is.na(stats)) == length(stats),]
```

Comment: Ah!  Brilliant!!  The only thing is, now the symbols, which should be in row 1, are all replaced by V1, V2, V3, etc., How can I get the actual symbols?

Also, if there are any errors are all, this pops up:
Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
  invalid 'row.names' length

How can I eliminate that?

Comment: That's because stats has less rows than the length of tickers. I've updated the answer to correct this

Comment: Yeap, that works.  Thanks so much.  I have to learn this stuff better.
Thanks again